# Creating a list using a loop, filling it with float()

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I'm currently working on a project that requires me to have a list from 0.9 to 1.2 with steps of 0.01. I tried the following:

```
init = float(0.9)
l = []
for i  in range(0,31):
  l[i]= init + ( float(i) / 100 )
```

However, python gives me the following output:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 2, in
>    IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Why you didn't do like that `i / 100.0`. And why you make float from float in `float(0.9)`?

Answer (score 14):

`[]` works only if there is an element already at this index the list. Use [list.append()](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=append):

```
init = float(0.9)
l = []
for i  in range(0,31):
  l.append(init + ( float(i) / 100 ))
```

Once you are confortable with this, you can even use a comprehension list :

```
l = [init + (float(i) / 100 )) for i in range(0, 31)]
```

It is very rare in Python to use indexes. I understand a lot people do it because it's an habit in other languages, but most of the time, it's an anti-pattern in Python. If you you see a `i` somewhere, always wonder if you are not trying to reinvent the wheel.

BTW. Division has priority on addition so no need for parenthesis. Plus, `init = float(0.9)` is redundant. you can write `init = 0.9`. And the `/` always returns a float, therefor you can do :

```
l = []
for i in range(0, 31): 
  l.append(0.9 + i / 100)
```

Also note the way I place spaces. It's the [most used style convention in Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

And with a comprehension list :

```
l = [0.9 + i / 100 for i in range(0, 31)]
```

It is a much simpler way to achieve what you want. Don't worry, if your code works and you understand it, it's the most important. You don't NEED to do this. I'm just giving you this information so you can use it later if you wish.

Answer (score 3):

You need to extend the list. Use:

```
l.append(init + (float(i)/100))
```

or

```
l += [init + (float(i)/100)]
```

or even the more pythonic way

```
l = [init + (float(i)/100) for i in range(0, 31)]
```

Comment: You mean `append` instead of `extend`

Answer (score 3):

Use the [itertools](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) module:

```
In [8]: for i in itertools.count(0.9, 0.01):
   ...:    print i
   ...:    if i > 1.2:
   ...:        break
   ...:     
0.9
0.91
0.92
0.93
.
.
.
1.18
1.19
1.2
```

As pointed out in the comments, the `count()` can be combined with a [takewhile](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) in order to create a list-comprehension:

```
[i for i in itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x <= 1.2, itertools.count(0.9, 0.01))]
```

Comment: `itertools.count` is a useful starting point, but I'd wrap it in `itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x <= 1.2, itertools.count(0.9, 0.01))`

Comment: +1 for an alternative way of doing it. Itertools is packed with goodness and it's always great to ensure people hear about it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider appending the values to the list using l.append(), like this:

```
init = float(0.9)
l = []
for i  in range(0,31):
      a = init + (float(i)/100)
      l.append(a)
```

**Edit:** There is another way to do this, without using any list functions and just the random function (although the previous method is probably easier). Basically, you just create a random list and then replace the values in the list with the required values. Take a look:

```
import random
init = float(0.9)
l = [random.random() for i in range(0,31)]
for i  in range(0,31):
        l[i]= init + ( float(i) / 100 )
print l
```

It should work this way as well. But, this is only if you don't want to use any list functions. Still, the first script is easier and probably better.

Comment: Gah. Don't use `random` to prefill a list! It doesn't matter for a short list like this, but calls to `random.random()` are somewhat time-consuming. Use `None` or `0` as a placeholder. And you can create the list directly using multiplication: `[None] * 31`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign values to list on indexes which do not exist:

```
>>> abc = []
>>> abc[0] = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Use `append` , which appends the value in the list i.e. assigns it to the next index.

Or this can also be easily done using list comprehension:

```
>>> [ round(float(0.9) + (float(i) / 100 ),2) for i  in range(0,31)]
[0.9, 0.91, 0.92, 0.93, 0.94, 0.95, 0.96, 0.97, 0.98, 0.99, 1.0, 1.01, 1.02, 1.03, 1.04, 1.05, 1.06, 1.07, 1.08, 1.09, 1.1, 1.11, 1.12, 1.13, 1.14, 1.15, 1.16, 1.17, 1.18, 1.19, 1.2]
```

Note: I have used round to round everything up to 2 decimal digits. You can remove that part, if you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am overlooking something, you can do this with a list comprehension:

```
init = float(0.9)
l = [init + (float(i) / 100) for i in range(31)]
```

Whatever solution you end up using, consider floating point error and maybe use the `decimal.Decimal` class instead of floats. All solutions I tested with floating points produced rounding errors, eg:

```
>>> l
[0.9, 0.91, 0.92, 0.93, 0.9400000000000001, ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

About `.append()` you already was informed.

But there is another point: Due to the fact that `.01` cannot be represented in floatin point exactly, keeping on adding `.01` will sum up this error.

More exact would be to do

```
init = float(0.9)
end = float(1.21)
steps = 31

l = []
for i  in range(0,31):
    l.append((init * (steps - i) + end * i) / steps)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This- :

```
init = float(0.9)
l = [init + ( float(i) / 100 ) for i  in range(0,31)]
```

It will work :)

Answer (score 0):

Everyone has given great answers
however I thought why not a general function to solve this problem
i.e without knowing the range in advance (in this case range is 0-31)

`>>> l=[]`

```
>>> def addNumFun(startRange, endRange, interval):
          init = str(interval)[::-1].find('.')
          start = int(startRange * (10**init))
          end = int(endRange * (10**init))     
          for i in range(start,end):
             l.append(i/(10**init))
          l.append(end/(10**init))        # to add the last number of range

>>> addNumFun(0.9,1.2,0.01)
>>> l
[0.9, 0.91, 0.92, 0.93, 0.94, 0.95, 0.96, 0.97, 0.98, 0.99, 1.0, 1.01, 1.02, 1.03, 1.04, 1.05, 1.06, 1.07, 1.08, 1.09, 1.1, 1.11, 1.12, 1.13, 1.14, 1.15, 1.16, 1.17, 1.18, 1.19, 1.2, 0.9, 0.91, 0.92, 0.93, 0.94, 0.95, 0.96, 0.97, 0.98, 0.99, 1.0, 1.01, 1.02, 1.03, 1.04, 1.05, 1.06, 1.07, 1.08, 1.09, 1.1, 1.11, 1.12, 1.13, 1.14, 1.15, 1.16, 1.17, 1.18, 1.19, 1.2]
```